# Get URL from notification payload and set it as the URLRequest url from WKWebView in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a Web Application and it's also "wrapped" in a Swift 5 WebView (WKWebView) to have some native features, like notifications. Until now it's the only thing that we use native capabilities to, that's why until now we are keeping this format instead of writing a native from zero.

Now we decided that some notifications should open a specific route of the app. I've got the `url` in the notification `payload` and I can see it in Swift using following code:

```swift
// Background Notification
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {

    print("Notification payload: \(userInfo)")
}

// Foreground Notification
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    
    print("Notification payload: \(userInfo)")
    
    completionHandler(.newData)
}
```

But my problem is to pass this URL to the `ViewController` where I've implemented the `WKWebView`. I use for that, the following code:

```swift
override func loadView() {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    view = webView
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let appUrl = "http://localhost:3000" //for example
    
    let myURL = URL(string: appUrl)
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL)
    webView.load(myRequest)
}
```

Here I want the `appUrl` to be either `localhost` or the one when the user taps the specific notification with the `URL` in the `payload`.

Comment: There are multiple ways that this can be done. In case your webview is already initialized and you want to open the url once it arrives from remote notiifcation, you can setup a NotificationCenter notification which will notify the viewcontroller regarding the url and from there you can start loading it.

Comment: @Bharat thanks for your reply, there might be a lot of ways to do this, yes, but something to start would help, could you please provide any documentation or link to some relates related question to that you said? And another case is when the WebView is not already initialized too.